# How to make pause between each api call in springframework RestClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

This is a `org.springframework.web.client.RestClient` config

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {
    @Value("${experimental.host}")
    String baseURI;
    @Bean
    RestClient restClient(RestClient.Builder builder){
        return builder.baseUrl(baseURI).build();
    }
}
```

This is service which does a call to external API

```
@Component
public class RequestService {

    public String callAPI(int userID){
        Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of("id", userID);
        return restClient.post()
                .uri("/external")
                .body(properties)
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
    }
}
```

I get a list of user from db and in the loop call external API

```
@Service
public class RabbitMQProducer {

    private UserRepository repository;
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void sendUserData(){
        for(User user : repository.findAll()) {
            String data = requestService.callAPI(user.getID);
            ......
        }
    }   
}
```

What is a correct way to make a pause between each call because external api has constraine of 1 second to call ?
I got error message from API "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests: too many request 2 times in 1000 millseconds"

Is there any pattern or solution how to resolve that kind of problem ?

I think expected behavior:

call API --> 1 second wait --> call API --> 1 second wait ...

Easy way to fix that it's just to add `Thread.sleep(1000)` but i'm not sure that is a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Thread.sleep(1000), then it will make constraints of 1 call for 1 second, but it is not ideal because it will block the current thread.

## 1. Webflux & webClient

I use this.

```
   public Mono<String> callAPI(User user) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/external")
                .bodyValue(Map.of("id", user.getID()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1)); // Delay for each subscriber
    }
```

## 2. Resilience4j

This is the rate-limiting library.

```
import io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RateLimiter;
import io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RateLimiterConfig;
import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class RateLimiterConfig {

    @Bean
    public RateLimiter rateLimiter() {
        RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
            .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .limitForPeriod(1)
            .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .build();

        return RateLimiter.of("apiRateLimiter", config);
    }
}
```

.

```
@Service
public class RateLimitedRequestService {

    private final RequestService requestService;
    private final RateLimiter rateLimiter;

    public RateLimitedRequestService(RequestService requestService, RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
        this.requestService = requestService;
        this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
    }

    public String callAPI(User user) {
        return RateLimiter.decorateSupplier(rateLimiter, () -> requestService.callAPI(user.getID())).get();
    }
}
```

## 2. @Async

You should add @EnableAsync

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> callAPIWithDelay(User user, long delay) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            return requestService.callAPI(user.getID());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

## +a, retry

I recommend you add retry to ensure that works properly. When working with external API that has a rate limiting, it is recommended to make some retry logic.

Comment: As i understand you gave me a two different options .First i can use "Webflux & webClient" which is asynchronous but does not have retry . Second is to combine Resilience4j and RestClient which is synchronous but it has retry. Is that correct ?It looks like first options is easy to implement.

Comment: Is it good idea to combine Stream API and WebClient ?

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to create a separate thread and do the work.

```java
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> callAPIWithDelay(int userID, long delay) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of("id", userID);
            return restClient.post()
                .uri("/external")
                .body(properties)
                .retrieve()
                .body(String.class);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Using `@Async` creates a thread each time it is called, so it is recommended to use a threadpool. If you make the settings below, **SpringBoot** uses `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` through `autoConfiguration`.

```
spring:
  task:
    execution:
      pool:
        core-size: 5
        max-size: 5
        queue-capacity: 5
        keep-alive: 30s
```